# Datetiemfield saved to database but showing in adminsite is null

Tags: django, django-models

[Ordered_date was saved in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru2kk.png)
[But not display in adminsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SDwO.png)

My code:
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQYdD.png)
Please help me fix this issue

Comment: please include admin.py

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Do not post code as images: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask